# Show this map is a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that the map $\{ 0,\ldots,n-1\} \rightarrow \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, defined by $$x\mapsto x+a \text{ mod} n$$ belongs to $\mathcal{S_n}$,where $g.c.d(a,n)=1$ and I need a check.

---

To this aim, I want to show that this is a bijection:

- injectivity: $f(i)=f(j)$  implies $$(i+a) \text{mod}n = (j+a)\text{mod n}$$
  from which follows $$n|(i-j)$$ and hence $i-j$ is a multiple of $n$, therefore they're equal mod n. This proves injectivity
- surjectivity: I have to show that for every $j \in \{ 0,\ldots,n\}$ there exists $i \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $f(a)=i$, which means $$ (i+a)\text{ mod n} = j $$

which means that $$i+a = q*n + j$$ for some $q$ and hence $$i = j -a \text{ mod n}$$

Therefore I determined $i \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ and the proof is complete.

*Is everything okay?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. But a function from a finite set into itself is injective if and only it is surjective. So, proving injectivity is enough.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I wanted to construct it "by hands". My biggest doubt was if it was okay to reduce mod n at the end of every step. I don't know why I'm allowed

Comment: @bobinthebox, the canonical quotient map $\mathbb{Z}\ni n\mapsto{\bar n}\in\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ is an homomorphism. This means that you can operate with integers and take classes mod $N$ in the end or work directly mod $N$ at every step indifferently.

Answer (score 1):

The map is invertible, the inverse being $y\mapsto y-a$.

Invertible maps are bijective.